# effective search over an php iterator

Tags: php, algorithm, search, iterator, spl

I have a custom iterator (TokenIterator to be precise, which iterates, well, tokenized php code). Items are simple objects ("property bags" with some normalisation methods added)

I have to implement search functionality, which have to find if 
 1. one iterator contains another or 
 2. two (or more) iterators are overlapping (with some parametrisation).

Currently i use naive approach to (1)  - O(NxM) double loop search, and (2) is not implemented yet.

Before starting to reimplement really smart string-search algorithms I would like to know if there exists some effective implementation of that? Maybe something buried deep in some framework or generic library to reuse? And which algorithm will be most suitable here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is that you're talking about set operations, for which iterators are arguably not the best solution.

I don't know if there's any existing solution for your problem, but, as a general solution, I'd use hash tables. For example, construct a hash table using the tokens of the first set (I'll call it set from now on, since I feel Iterator is not the best word) and you can do it in Theta(N), and then try to insert the other set in the same hash table. The first time you get a collision, you'll know there's an overlap. Of course this works well if the hash space is wide and the hash function guarantees a negligible amount of collisions, however it is always possible to code some sort of workaround.

Given PHP has associative arrays (which are a form of hash tables) you can also create an array having the tokens as the keys, which again can be done in Theta(N), and then use array_key_exists. It is absolutely possible that array_key_exists is nothing more than a linear scan of the list of keys, as I am not familiar with PHP's internals, but I'm quite confident that if associative arrays are implemented as hash tables, it should be implemented much more efficiently than a linear scan.

Comment: using php arrays to make the job is not a problem; problem is casting an iterator to array (which needs to iterate over all elements) and (eventually) recasting it after. So, I was trying to find solution which can make the same and iterates over all items only in worst case

Comment: I fail to understand your point. You said you need to check whether a set is included into another or at least overlaps another. Doing so with Iterators would definitely need a nested loop search that yelds a Theta(NxM) complexity. Using arrays lowers the complexity to O(N+M) since it doesn't require nested loops and gives you the answer you're looking for. The only reason I see for having to cast arrays back to iterators is if you need to *perform* boolean operations with those sets, but that's not what you asked for. :)

Comment: And even in that case, there's no actual need to cast arrays back. The boolean operations can be performed the same way the tests are.

Comment: Misunderstanding: I must use iterator. So if I want to do anything using arrays, I have to cast this iterator to array before. From that comes overhead which I ma trying to avoid by developing custom search. And effectively, substracting sets is # 3 on my list (although is quite simple once you find all positions)

Comment: I'm afraid iterators won't allow any algorithm more efficient than O(NxM). Casting an iterator to an array takes Theta(N) (given N the size of the set) and casting it back yelds the same complexity, but these operations are chained, not nested, so basically we're speaking of Theta(2N) = Theta(N) for the casts. Then comes the search part, which is Theta(M) (M the size of the second) set, hence Theta(N+M+N) = Theta(N+M) for the whole algorithm. The effective operations can be performed by taking collisions and constructing another iterable structure with them, or whatever it's appropriate.

Comment: Here's a sample implementation. http://pastebin.com/ZsX8eZFT (possible misundersanting: I wasn't speaking of actual iterator->array cast, but making an array having iterator's items as keys, which should exploit hash magic powers :)

Comment: I think i will use your approach, finally. Maybe hiding it nicely into iterator itself :)

Answer (score 1):

If your iterators can be casted to arrays, you can use `array_diff` and `array_intersect`. Otherwise you have to implement what these functions do under the hood - walk over your structures and compare.
Because the data you iterate is not sorted nor do you know anything else about it, you have no other choice.

Comment: effectively, casting iterator to array implies iterating whole thing, so there is not much to gain here.